# Add and save 'background' information or text in an Excel or Powerpoint file

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I don't really know how to express what I'm looking for, so I'll give a bit of context:

I have and add-in for Excel and PowerPoint that allows the user to insert shapes into the worksheet/slide with specific sizes, colors and values to form a stylized chart. I don't use the integrated charts because my company needs some weird styles and parameters that I can only replicate using shapes.

The problem is that once the shapes are in the worksheet/slide the user cannot go back to the add-in and change the chart values or series. For example, a user can't redefine the values and instead of $50 put $90 and update automatically the chart (as with the Office charts that we all know and love).

[image: An example of the shapes inserted into the a slide]

**So** what I thought as a solution is to have a 'background text file' or something like that with a dictionary of the charts and the shapes that are part of it; also the values and other characteristics like the x and y axis values. This way, when the user goes back to the add-in, he/she can retreive all the info from the original chart and change values, parameters or whatever is neeeded -- using the shapes' dictionary.

In essence, I want to program something like Think-cell but in Visual Basic.

Any suggestion is very welcomed!

Comment: Please include the code you created in your attempt in your question if you would like help with it.

Comment: PowerPoint doesn't have many good places in a file to store hidden information. Custom Document Properties are your best bet for VBA. Second place would be a hidden slide, but you can't stop users from viewing them and making them visible. If you step up to VB in Visual Studio, you can write a VSTO add-in that can add custom XML parts to a presentation to store data. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/create-vsto-add-ins-for-office-by-using-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: I'll take issue with @JohnKorchok Custom Document properties are useful for small amounts of information, but a) users can see/modify them and b) there's a limited amount of storage allocated to them; put too much info in there and you'll start overwriting other info that's already there. Instead look into tags, either at the presentation level or on individual slides and shapes. More on tags on my PPT FAQ page: Working with Tags (and a bit about Functions)
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00815_Working_with_Tags_-and_a_bit_about_Functions-.htm

Comment: Steve, I think tags will do the trick. I had no idea these were an option. I might be able to add tags such as "ChartID", "Series", "Value", etc. And even when a user deletes some of the shapes, I might be able to reconstruct the whole chart with the rest of the tags. I'll keep you posted on this. Thank you so much!